# Communicate webview and parent window in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to replace iframe with [webview tag](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag). How to listen to the message from the child window?

While using iframe, it was like this

index.html (local)

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
   if (event.data === "hide-loader") {
     //hide loader window
   }
});
```

I'm loading my app from remote URL in webview tag (formerly an iframe)
remote app [posting message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to parent like below

app.html (remote)

```
parent​Window.post​Message("hide-loader");
```

Can I listen to the same events without changing my remote app code?

Comment: Without changing your code, I kind of doubt it. Look into using a [preload script](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#preload) in your webview to expose some APIs to your remote app, which will call `ipcRenderer.send` internally to send messages to the main process. That's at least the standard way of doing this

Comment: I feel using the preload script is a kind of hacking. It's like injecting code into app loaded from remote URL

Comment: well, if you've stuck your remote app in a sandboxed process, that's the idiomatic way of doing it in Electron. Is this a remote app that you control (you've written?)

Comment: Yes, If that's not possible can elaborate better way to do it?